# What is a good way to speed up test runs utilizing larger spacy models?

Tags: python, testing, spacy

I have constructed some tests relying on the `en_core_web_md` model. The model takes ~15 sec to load into memory on my computer making the tests a pain to run.

Is there a smart way to speed it up?

Comment: Please, give an [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The v2.2.[0-5] `md` models have a minor bug that make them particularly slow to load (see https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/pull/4990).

You can reformat one file in the model package to improve the load time.
In the `vocab` directory for the model package (e.g., `lib/python3.7/site-packages/en_core_web_md/en_core_web_md-2.2.5/vocab`):

```
import srsly
orig_data = srsly.read_msgpack("key2row")
new_data = {}
for key, value in orig_data.items():
    new_data[int(key)] = int(value)
srsly.write_msgpack("key2row", new_data)
```

In my tests, this nearly halves the loading time (18s to 10s). The remaining time is mostly loading strings and lexemes for the model, which is harder to optimize further at this point. So this improves things a bit but the overall load time is still relatively burdensome for short tests.

Comment: Very interesting. I'm getting `NameError: name 'np' is not defined` when running `orig_data = srsly.read_msgpack("key2row")` though

Comment: Hmm, check that you have `numpy` installed. (I think there might be a setup config mistake in `srsly` where you could install `srsly` without `numpy`, but I'm not sure how you ended up with `spacy` and not `numpy`...)

Comment: Yes, that was it! The loading time went down from ~15 to ~8 sec. Nice improvement indeed but as you say still quite burdensome