# Python: Spacy NER and memory consumption

Tags: python, memory, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I use SPACY for named entity recognition. I have my own trained model on en_core_web_md. The size of my model is 223 megabytes. When the model is loaded into memory, it uses 800 megabytes. Is it possible somehow for NER purposes not to load everything (lexemes.bin, string.json, key2row), but only vectors and model (which weigh 4 and 24 megabytes respectively) to consume much less memory? or is it all necessary to load for NER?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For spacy v2.2, it is necessary to load everything. There is one minor bug that affects `key2row` in `md` models: to improve the size and loading time of `key2row` in `md` models with versions `v2.2.0-v2.2.5`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60541041/461847.

The bug related to `key2row` is fixed in v2.2.4 if you're training a model from scratch with your own custom vectors, but the provided v2.2 `md` models will still have this issue.

Planned for v2.3: removal of `lexemes.bin` with lexemes only created on demand. With these changes, the `md` models will be about 50% smaller on disk and the initial model loading is about 50% faster. The English `md` model looks like it's about 300MB smaller in memory when loaded initially, but memory usage will increase a bit in use as it builds a lexeme cache. See: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/pull/5238